# mPDF class not found

Tags: php, mpdf

This code, taken directly from the mPDF manual, causes an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables' not
>   found in /HW.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /HW.php on line 4

.

Can anyone help?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$defaultConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\ConfigVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontDirs = $defaultConfig['fontDir'];

$defaultFontConfig = (new Mpdf\Config\FontVariables())->getDefaults();
$fontData = $defaultFontConfig['fontdata'];

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
        __DIR__ . '/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/extrafonts/Open_Sans/',
    ]),
    'fontdata' => $fontData + [
        'open_sans' => [
            'R' => 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf',
            'I' => 'OpenSans-Italic.ttf',
            'B' => 'OpenSans-Bold.ttf',
        ]
    ],
    'default_font' => 'open_sans'
]);
?>
```

Comment: Did you install mPDF version 7 via composer?

Comment: Please see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error turned out to be caused by MacOSX lacking PHP version 7. In its absence, Composer installed mPDF version 6 which is compatible with PHP 5.5, which is what MacOSX has (at least in v 10.10.5, which is what I have). The code I posted above requires mPDF version 7 and thus caused an error when used with mPDF version 6. There is a purported solution for installing PHP 7 on MacOSX called php_osx but so far I have failed to make it work on my machine (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478784/php-osx-installed-php-7-phpinfo-and-composer-still-think-its-php5-5)).
My solution for now is to stick with mPDF version 6 and adjust the code accordingly (there is an mPDF version 6 manual still up [here](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Download)).