# php_osx installed php 7, phpinfo() and composer still think its php5.5

Tags: php, bash, macos

Question specifically for the php_osx developers:

I followed your instructions and installed php 7.1 on my Mac running 10.10.5.(command `curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1`) Everything looked ok, but when running a composer.phar script, it says I can't  require the latest version of a package at Packagist since my PHP is version 5. `phpinfo()` also says it's version 5. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the right module of PHP in your Apache settings (`httpd.conf`).

```
#LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.29_5/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.8_20/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Then you have to restart your Apache server for the changes to apply.

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Thank you. Please excuse my ignorance here, but how do I do this? Is the code above to be entered into httpd.conf? And how is Apache server restarted?

Comment: @danbae Yes that is the code to put into your `httpd.conf`. Take a look at my update for how to restart Apache.

Comment: Sorry this is not working. In the `httpd.config`file, it looked like this first: `...#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so
...` I then copied the `libphp7.so` file into  `libexec/apache2` and wrote `LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so` in the config. After restarting Apache, `phpinfo()` still says it is running 5.5.38. What is wrong?